# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition: close search window

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition, and I would like to know if it is possible to close the window to find, I don't see the close button anywhere

[image]

Comment: In phpstorm just press "esc"  key. I think it's the same on intellij IDEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you can just use Esc to close the window. In your case, the window is pinned, unpin by clicking the button on the upright corner.